# Access to list element on codebehind from aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following method on codebehind

```
Public List<object> Exec()
{
    List<object> result = New List<object>();
    DataTable results = New DataTable();

    // methodToExecuteSP is = public DataSet 
    results = methodToExecuteSP;

    foreach (DataRow i in results.Rows)
    {
        result.Add(new { Name = i[“Name”] });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then on my aspx I have the following html and C# code

```
<tbody>
    <% foreach (var item in Exec()) { %>
        <tr><td><%=item.Name %> </td></tr>
    <% } %>
</tbody>
```

This shows the following error message:

> Object does not contain a definition for Name.

What I’m doing wrong?

PD: If I change item.Name to item I can see my entire list properly.

Comment: Why don't you simply build a `List<string>` instead?

Comment: Anonymous methods exist when you want to use the object *within the scope of that method*.  When you want the object to be used from multiple methods, you shouldn't use an anonymous object.

Comment: Maybe you want to create a new class eg Class Student with only one property "Name" and then you can do List<Student>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Note the return type of the method `Exec`, it is `object`. This type has not any property called `Name`. That you need is to change this return type to an object with the property you want to use, `Name` or to just return a `List<string>`, if the only property you are going to use is the `Name`.

*first approach*:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public List<Person> Exec()
{
    var persons = new List<Person>();

    var results = New DataTable();

    // methodToExecuteSP is = public DataSet 
    results = methodToExecuteSP;

    foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
    {
        result.Add(new Person { Name = row[“Name”].ToString() });
    }

    return persons;
}

<tbody>
<% foreach (var person in Exec()) { %>
    <tr><td><%=person.Name %> </td></tr>
<% } %>
</tbody>
```

*second approach*:

```
public List<string> Exec()
{
    var names = new List<string>();

    var results = New DataTable();

    // methodToExecuteSP is = public DataSet 
    results = methodToExecuteSP;

    foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
    {
        result.Add(row[“Name”].ToString());
    }

    return names;
}

<tbody>
<% foreach (var name in Exec()) { %>
    <tr><td><%=name%> </td></tr>
<% } %>
</tbody>
```